# Correct usage of "be / am"

Tags: grammaticality

There is this quote from "How I Met Your Mother":

> When I get sad I stop being sad and **be** awesome instead.

Why can you use "be" in this sentence? Doesn't it have to be:

> When I get sad I stop being sad and **(I) am** awesome instead.

Comment: **[Related question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104679/when-im-sad-i-stop-being-sad-and-be-awesome-instead)**

Comment: If it was *am*, he is already awesome. I think in the first sentence the person is using *be awesome* as an imperative and not invoking the subjunctive.

Comment: Like "will be" with "will" left out.

Comment: The original is certainly awkward, and may be ungrammatical (I am not sure if it technically is or not).  The speaker is almost surely aware of its awkwardness, and is making this almost childlike "mistake" for effect.  Your rewrite sounds okay to me, but I think replacing "am" with "become" would be better if you're interested in rewriting the sentence in a standard way.

Answer (score 1):

The use of *be* is incorrect. There are many grammatical errors or inconsistencies in the media - many are intentional for some stylistic reason, many are not. Here perhaps the script is supposed to be funny.

Incorrect language may be used because it is more suitable for the character being portrayed, or, as sometimes appears to be the case, because the scriptwriter does not know the correct English.